# Developing custom visuals in Power BI

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powerbi, pbiviz

Is the code for Power BI **Line and stacked column chart** and **KPI** visuals available? If so, where can they be retrieved?

The purpose is to enhance the visuals:

1. The axis lines are missing from the chart
2. Bolding the numbers in KPI is not possible as well, as I want to rename **goal** to target

So, I am trying the find out if I can edit the existing code or do I have to start from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

**Source code of Power BI Core Visuals aren't available**

You need to consider to use another Custom Visual with source code

Probably PKI Chart by Akvelon meets to your requirements:

https://github.com/akvelon/PowerBI-KPI-Chart

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381432

And Advance Card supports bolding font:

https://github.com/bhavesh-jadav/Advance-Card/

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381651